# Hibernate Spatial and legacy db

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-spatial

**Background:**

I have legacy db and I cannot change its schema.
Mapping of my entity looks like:

```
class SomeObject {
    @Column(name = "LONGITUDE", nullable = false)
    public BigDecimal longitude;

    @Column(name = "LATITUDE", nullable = false)
    public BigDecimal latitude;

    ...
}
```

**Problem:**

I need to create hibernate query which will select all **SomeObjects** in a circle.
I through **hibernate spatial** should be right tool to solve this problem.
But, all examples which I can find declare column of type **Point** instead of using separate columns for coordinates as I have.
Since I cannot change db schema such approach will not work for me.

So, can I use hibernate spatial to solve this problem?
If yes how query will look like?

**Solution:**

Karthik Prasad clearly and correctly described what is spatial and what options I have in general.
Since, I am using Oracle DB I had one more option: use sdo_geom package.
So, at the end instead of hibernate query/criteria I used SQL query:

```
select * 
from SOMETHING
where 
-- add box to decrease number of records
-- where box is radius converted to degree by multiply on (1. / 69.) * 1.1 
:lon - :box < longitude and longitude < :lon + :box and 
:lat - :box < latitude and latitude < :lat + :box and 
sdo_geom.sdo_distance(
  sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(longitude, latitude)),
  sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(:lon, :lat)),
  1, 'unit=mile') < :radius
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate Spatial is specifically operates on Database having type Geometry with/without Spatial Indexes. Only options I think off is create clone table with another column added with geometry type point(or as per your usecase) your database enabled with Spatial extension/module.

Comment: I spent some time by myself to realize that "Hibernate Spatial is specifically operates on Database having type Geometry with/without Spatial Indexes." as you said.
Since it was first time when I worked with spatial it was not clear for me :(.
As result I end up using Oracle sdo_geom package